# How to display text for 2 seconds in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a racing game with pygame. When the car crashes into one of the walls it's supposed to display "YOU CRASHED" message. It is doing this, but it only shows it for a fraction of a second then it resets the game and you have to play again. The part where it says `def_crash()` is where I give the command to display the text.

Here is the code of the game:

````
import time
import random

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

red = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)

bright_red = (255,0,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)


car_width = 86

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Racing Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load("download.png")
carImg = pygame.transform.scale(carImg,(100,160))

def things_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render ("Dodged: "+str(count), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,0))

def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (x,y))

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",100)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    game_loop()

    time.sleep(2)

def crash():
    message_display ("YOU CRASHED")

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action = None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    print(click)
    if x + w > mouse [0] > x and y + h > mouse [1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "play":
                game_loop()

            elif action == "quit":
                pygame.quit()
                quit()


    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, (x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText) 
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)


def game_intro():
    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",100)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Racing Game", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


        button ("GO!",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,"play")
        button ("QUIT!",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,"quit")





        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)



def game_loop():
    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.72)

    x_change = 0

    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 7
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100

    thingCount = 1

    dodged = 0


    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

        x += x_change

        gameDisplay.fill(white)


        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, black)
        thing_starty += thing_speed
        car (x,y)
        things_dodged(dodged)

        if x > display_width - car_width or x < -10:
            crash()


        if thing_starty > display_height:
            thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
            thing_startx = random.randrange(0,display_width)
            dodged += 1
            thing_speed += 1
            thing_width += (dodged * 0.5)


        if y < thing_starty + thing_height:


            if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x + car_width > thing_startx and x + car_width < thing_startx + thing_width: 
                crash()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(80)

game_intro()        
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()```



Please help if possible. If you can tell me what's wrong and tell me how to fix it that would be great.
````

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way would be to do something like this. All I changed was your `crash` function and added a little code where it was called. I also removed some lines in `display_message`.

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)


car_width = 86

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Racing Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load("download.png")
carImg = pygame.transform.scale(carImg,(100,160))


def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (x,y))

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",100)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    # Don't do any of these.
    # pygame.display.update()
    # game_loop()
    # time.sleep(2)


def crash_scene(x, y):
    sceneExit = False
    time = 2000  # 2000 milliseconds until we continue.

    while not sceneExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        car (x,y)
        message_display ("YOU CRASHED")

        pygame.display.update()

        passed_time = clock.tick(60)
        time -= passed_time
        if time <= 0:
            sceneExit = True

def game_loop():
    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.72)

    x_change = 0


    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

        x += x_change

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        car (x,y)

        if x > display_width - car_width or x < -10:
            crash_scene(x, y)
            # Reset car
            x = (display_width * 0.45)
            y = (display_height * 0.72)
            x_change = 0

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Basically, when you need to change how events are handled, how game objects are updated or how things are drawn, create an own little function for that. Other examples would be a menu, a pause screen or a cut-scene. In the example above I did the absolute minimum to get started, so there are some issues with the code, but it should work.

Comment: I tried this out but it did not work and it just flashed "YOU CRASHED" for a fraction of a second before restarting the game. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Python123 Yeah, my bad. I expected `message_display` to just display the message, but it's also calling back to the `game_loop`. You should remove that call (as Rabbid76 mentions).

Comment: Thank You. This is working now, but I added a lot to my code and something doesn't seem right because it isn't working again. Please let me know what I have to change by looking at the code that I changed in the initial question.

Comment: Your `crash` function is very different from what I showed in my answer. Take a look again and try to understand what's happening. Also, you shouldn't change the question whenever you have a different question. Create a new question instead.

Comment: I tried to figure out what's wrong, but I couldn't find out. If you can help out, thank you and if you can't it's okay.

Comment: Your `crash` function is only displaying the message (which will happen in an instance), but what you need to do is what I've done in the `crash_scene` function